# Can you connect iPhone to LDAP on a non-standard port?

Tags: ios, ldap

In a nutshell, I believe I'm having issues configuring iOS to connect to LDAP on a non-standard port.

I've tried a quite a few different sequences, such as appending the port to the server address, but all to no avail. Has anyone been able to connect to an LDAP that runs on a different port than 389? If so, I would appreciate confirmation that it is possible and steps on how you set things up would be even better.

My LDAP is apacheDS and the port it runs on is not 389, so I'm at a loss how an iPhone or iPad can connect to the LDAP.

Comment: I have tried to edit the question into better shape. I would leave this question here to see if anyone knows of iOS settings for LDAP. You might ask a question tailored to ServerFault where you ask for setup steps / best practices for configuring apacheDS on non-standard ports for consumption of DS by iOS. I'm fairly certain you'll get some good advice there as well.

Comment: how to connect to a ldap server? with openldap?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, iOS doesn't (as of 5.0) support accessing an LDAP server on any port other than 389.

Comment: Thanks you. I don't know if this is right, but if so, I won't waste more effort, since 389 will connect

Comment: If only 389 is supported that would be pretty concerning, since it also permits providing a username/password.  Transmitting your clear-text username/password seems like a pretty bad idea.  Generally ldap on 389 has no encryption.

Comment: iOS will try and make a connection via TLS (still on port 389) and only fall back to clear-text if TLS isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

Most hostname/address fields accept a port in a standard syntax form. I can't test this as I don't have access to an LDAP server on a non-standard port, but hopefully this works for you:

[image]

Note the `:5385` is my made up port number, obviously you want to enter whatever your LDAP server runs on. Most fields such as browser address bars and other connection strings accept port designation in that matter, immediately following the hostname or IP address, before any additional information.

HTTP web browsing has an implicit :80 that browsers don't show, ditto for HTTPS and :443. If you browsed to http://google.com:80/, your browser would simply strip the :80 but everything would behave normally.

Comment: so far my experience has lead me to believe that the appended port is not used if you designate it